# Subsonic 2.2 varchar2 maxlength problem

Tags: oracle, subsonic, subsonic2.2

I have a problem with saving 4000 characters to varchar2(4000) oracle 10g column 
it lets me save just 2000 characters and when I try to save exceeding 2000 character

I get tihs error

Can't save: GENERAL_ NOTE exceeds the maximum length of 4000

this is subsonic column definition 
                               TableSchema.TableColumn colvarGeneralNote = new
                                TableSchema.TableColumn(schema);
                colvarGeneralNote.ColumnName = "GENERAL_NOTE";
                colvarGeneralNote.DataType = DbType.String;
                colvarGeneralNote.MaxLength = 4000;
                colvarGeneralNote.AutoIncrement = false;
                colvarGeneralNote.IsNullable = true;
                colvarGeneralNote.IsPrimaryKey = false;
                colvarGeneralNote.IsForeignKey = false;
                colvarGeneralNote.IsReadOnly = false;
                colvarGeneralNote.DefaultSetting = @"";
                colvarGeneralNote.ForeignKeyTableName = "";
                schema.Columns.Add(colvarGeneralNote);

I can't save a string with exceeding 2000 characters to my varchar2(4000) column

Please advise me for that issue

Thanks - Adem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it could mean that you are inserting multi-byte data.
try changing field definition to : varchar2(4000 char)

also what is nls_length_semantics in your db and the Characterset.

Comment: The maximum length of a VARCHAR2 is 4000 bytes. You won't fit any more than that in there, whatever the DB character set.

Answer (score 0):

I changed field definition to varchar2(4000 char) and my db settings as follows NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS BYTE 
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16

I also find that when characters when charactes count between 2000 and 4000 I got ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested error and when character count higher than 4000 I got  Can't save: GENERAL_ NOTE exceeds the maximum length of 4000 error Now

Thanks Adem